# oracle sqlloader paraller mode

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, sql-loader

When we are talking about parallel mode with sqlloader what does that actually mean? When i have in my script to execute:

```
Sqlldr control=first.ctl parallel=true direct=true data=first.unl
Sqlldr control=second.ctl parallel=true direct=true data=second.unl
```

I am inserting into 2 tables using as a data file for the inserts of the first table the first.unl and for the 2nd table the second.unl

By having parallel=true and direct=true will this run the 2 instances of sqlloader for first.unl and second.unl in parallel or will it run the first instance and do multiple inserts based on the first.unl and the run the second instance and do multiple inserts again based on the second.unl?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_params.htm#i1004826)

> "PARALLEL specifies whether direct loads can operate in multiple concurrent sessions to load data into the same table."

So, one instance of SQL Loader uses multiple sessions to insert into one table.   The actual degree of parallelism is governed by the usual parallelization parameters.

> "So i cannot have inserting into multiple tables in parallel?"

If you kick off two SQL Loader instances they will run simultaneously.  You need to be careful that you have enough CPU to handle the number of threads you're spawning.

Comment: So i cannot have inserting into multiple tables in parallel?